# Get information from already created object

Tags: object, javafx, getter-setter

I will try to be as clear as possible. I have an object `ButtonData` which have setters and getters. In class `InfoController` I create an object and, set data to `ButtonData`. I want to get this data in another class `Controller`and use already stored data in class `ButtonData`, but I can't create a new Object and get information, because it will be clear. How when access to data which is stored in ButtonData?

InfoController:

```html
@FXML
void onSaveClick(ActionEvent event) {
  if(parseInputs()) {
    ButtonData setData = new ButtonData();

    setData.setCode(code);
    setData.setCompany(company);
    setData.setCountry(country);
  }
}
```

Controller (here I want to get data):

```html
@FXML
void addFlag(ActionEvent event) {
  ButtonData setData = new ButtonData(); //CAN'T DO LIKE THIS!
        
  addingFlag.pinFlag(imageView, anchPane);
  addingFlag.setButtonID(setData.getCode());

  String getCompany = setData.getCompany();
 }
```

Comment: What language is this? and which platform?

Comment: Java - javafx. I thought it was obvious

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.